# nginx proxy pass forward subdirectory & preserve url

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have setup two servers with nginx -

1. https://dev.imagecompressor.io at 35.231.119.158
2. https://imagecompressor.io at 176.9.41.138

I am trying to forward `https://imagecompressor.io/site` to `https://dev.imagecompressor.io/site` & want the url remain `https://imagecompressor.io/site`.

Forwarding is doing ok but the subdirectory `/site/` seems to be omitted & URL is also changed.

NGINX configuration at 176.9.41.138

```
location /site/ {
        proxy_pass http://dev.imagecompressor.io;
        # error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log debug;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host imagecompressor.io;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change this line:

```
proxy_pass http://dev.imagecompressor.io;
```

to this:

```
proxy_pass http://dev.imagecompressor.io/site;
```

And if you want to change URL to  new URL use this:

```
proxy_set_header Host  http://dev.imagecompressor.io;
```

else you can use it:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

Comment: Suffixing `/site` does not seem to work. 301 redirect is still to https://dev.imagecompressor.io/. `$host` has no effect at all.

Comment: Sorry that I replied so late, I will test it and update my answer soon.